# Handling/troubleshooting errors with helper scripts in arcgis module

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I am fairly new to python and need recommendations on how to handle internal/helper function failures.

I have a script that that imports a list of jurisdictions, then iterates through that list and creates a view, map, and experience builder application tailored to that jurisdiction. It's working more or less flawlessly but is routinely failing on the third iteration. And the failure happens due to an error with the arcgis\features\managers.py helper.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\user\path_to_project\script.py in <cell line: 40>()
     224 for j in jList: #changed 'jurisdiction' to 'j'
     225     #*Create Views
---> 226     jView = masterLayer.manager.create_view(name = j + '_view',      spatial_reference = sr, tags = tagsText, capabilities = "Create,Query,Update,Delete,Editing,ChangeTracking")
     227     jView.move(folder = folder)
     228     jViewFLC = arcgis.features.FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(jView)

c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\managers.py in create_view(self, name, spatial_reference, extent, allow_schema_changes, updateable, capabilities, view_layers, view_tables, description, tags, snippet, overwrite, set_item_id, preserve_layer_ids)
   2006             params["description"] = description
   2007         res = gis._con.post(path=url, postdata=params)
-> 2008         view = content.get(res["itemId"])
   2009         fs_view = FeatureLayerCollection(url=view.url, gis=gis)
   2010         add_def = {"layers": [], "tables": []}

KeyError: 'itemId'
```

The loop runs all the way through the first two items in the list and then fails routinely on the third. It was running all the way through two days ago and nothing has changed with this aspect of the script.

How do I isolate the error when it happens within the package?

Answer (score 0):

This Python error handler (with traceback) for arcpy is a useful piece of code to include with all your scripts.  It might provide you with more information on troubleshooting your problem.  [See here for more help with error handlers in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/arcpy/get-started/error-handling-with-python.htm).  [Here is some basic information on KeyErrors](https://rollbar.com/blog/python-keyerror/#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20KeyError%20is%20an,which%20leads%20to%20the%20KeyError%20.).

```
import arcpy
import sys
import traceback
try:

    #------------

    Your indented code goes here

    #------------


except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
    # Get the tool error messages 
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 

    # Return tool error messages for use with a script tool 
    arcpy.AddError(msgs) 

    # Print tool error messages for use in Python
    print(msgs)

except:
    # Get the traceback object
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]

    # Concatenate information together concerning the error into a message string
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

    # Return Python error messages for use in script tool or Python window
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)

    # Print Python error messages for use in Python / Python window
    print(pymsg)
    print(msgs)
```

Comment: Is this valid if I'm not using ArcPy? This is all using the python API for AGOL so it's all in the arcgis module, not ArcPy.

Comment: Oh, no, you would need to import arcpy for most of that to work. Here is a link for error handing with the Python API.  https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/advanced-concepts/.  And there is plenty on the internet for basic error handling with Python:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exception-handling/